# Using session variables to generate GROUP information

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, session

We want to know whether the given approach is correct or not. I understand that there might other and presumably better and more optimized ways of accomplishing the task. But it is a curiosity that I want to fulfill. Consider it an academic exercise.
Consider the following two tables :

```
    TABLE-ONE                   TABLE-TWO
+----+-----------+         +----+-------+-------+
| id | key       |         | id | fk_id | value |
+----+-----------+         +----+-------+-------+
|  1 | k1        |         |  1 | 1     | v1    |
|  2 | k2        |         |  2 | 1     | v2    |
|  3 | k3        |         |  3 | 1     | v3    |
+----+-----------+         |  4 | 2     | v1    |
                           |  5 | 2     | v2    |
                           |  6 | 3     | v1    |
                           |  7 | 3     | v2    |
                           |  8 | 3     | v3    |
                           |  9 | 3     | v4    |
                           | 10 | 3     | v5    |
                           +----+-------+-------+
```

We need to JOIN these two tables and ORDER the result on TABLE-ONE.id
The resultant table should look like :

```
+----+-------+-------+----------------+
| id | key   | value | is_first_entry |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | k1    | v1    |  1             |
|  1 | k1    | v2    |  0             |
|  1 | k1    | v3    |  0             |
|  2 | k2    | v1    |  1             |
|  2 | k2    | v2    |  0             |
|  3 | k3    | v1    |  1             |
|  3 | k3    | v2    |  0             |
|  3 | k3    | v3    |  0             |
|  3 | k3    | v4    |  0             |
|  3 | k3    | v5    |  0             |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+
```

The is_first_entry column should return 1 if it is the first entry for that key in the result-set. Else it should return zero.
One way of achieving this is by via an INNER JOIN. We were exploring the option of achieving the result without the self join
by using session-variables.

To achieve this, we first created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `is_first_entry`( _id INT) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

IF @current_id is NULL
THEN
  SET @current_id = _id;
  RETURN 1;
END IF;

IF @current_id = _id
THEN
  RETURN 0;
ELSE 
  SET @current_id = _id;
  RETURN 1;
END IF;

END
```

The final query that we created to achieve the result.

```
SELECT one.id, one.key, two.value, is_first_entry(one.id) as is_first_entry
FROM TABLE-ONE one
INNER JOIN TABLE-TWO two
ON one.id = two.fk_id;
INNER JOIN (SELECT @current_id := 1 as v) t
on 1 = 1
ORDER BY one.id;
```

Even though it is working for **small data set**.
Will it give correct result **on scale** ?
Can someone think of a scenario/example where this technique might break. It is okay, if this query executes slowly.
For the time being, we are only concerned about the **correctness** and not about **optimization.**

Answer (score 0):

You asked if I had a counter point, yes I have.

Your list is unsorted and therefore gives a false result. if a later value comes to the mix.

Only when  you don't let latecomers into your table, it would hold.

To solve the problem with the late comers, you first have to get is_first value from a sorted table-two and inner join t1 later.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `TABLE-TWO`   (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `fk_id` INTEGER,
>   `value` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `TABLE-TWO`  
>   (`id`, `fk_id`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'v1'),
>   ('2', '1', 'v2'),
>   ('3', '1', 'v3'),
>   ('4', '2', 'v1'),
>   ('5', '2', 'v2'),
>   ('6', '3', 'v1'),
>   ('7', '3', 'v2'),
>   ('8', '3', 'v3'),
>   ('9', '3', 'v4'),
>   ('10', '3', 'v5'),
>   ('11', '2', 'v3');
>
> CREATE TABLE `TABLE-ONE` (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `key` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `TABLE-ONE`
>   (`id`, `key`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'k1'),
>   ('2', 'k2'),
>   ('3', 'k3');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION `is_first_entry`( _id INT) RETURNS int(11)
> BEGIN
>
> IF @current_id is NULL
> THEN
>   SET @current_id = _id;
>   RETURN 1;
> END IF;
>
> IF @current_id = _id
> THEN
>   RETURN 0;
> ELSE 
>   SET @current_id = _id;
>   RETURN 1;
> END IF;
>
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   t2a.id
>     ,t1.key
>     ,t2a.value,IF(t2b.minid = t2a.id,1,0) is_first_entry
> FROM
> `TABLE-TWO` t2a 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) minid,fk_id FROM `TABLE-TWO` GROUP BY fk_id) t2b ON t2a.fk_id = t2b. fk_id 
> INNER JOIN `TABLE-ONE` t1 ON t1.id = t2a.fk_id
> ORDER By id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | key | value | is_first_entry
> -: | :-- | :---- | -------------:
>  1 | k1  | v1    |              1
>  2 | k1  | v2    |              0
>  3 | k1  | v3    |              0
>  4 | k2  | v1    |              1
>  5 | k2  | v2    |              0
>  6 | k3  | v1    |              1
>  7 | k3  | v2    |              0
>  8 | k3  | v3    |              0
>  9 | k3  | v4    |              0
> 10 | k3  | v5    |              0
> 11 | k2  | v3    |              0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT one.id, one.key, two.value, is_first_entry(one.id) as is_first_entry
> FROM `TABLE-ONE` one
> INNER JOIN `TABLE-TWO` two
> ON one.id = two.fk_id;
> INNER JOIN (SELECT @current_id := 1 as v) t
> on 1 = 1
> ORDER BY one.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | key | value | is_first_entry
> -: | :-- | :---- | -------------:
>  1 | k1  | v1    |              1
>  1 | k1  | v2    |              0
>  1 | k1  | v3    |              0
>  2 | k2  | v1    |              1
>  2 | k2  | v2    |              0
>  3 | k3  | v1    |              1
>  3 | k3  | v2    |              0
>  3 | k3  | v3    |              0
>  3 | k3  | v4    |              0
>  3 | k3  | v5    |              0
>  2 | k2  | v3    |              1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=60d9203778ab0d83a200938f6e1b182b)*

As id is your only indicator for your first selection you can do it simply by choosing the minimum of id

```
SELECT 
    t2a.id
    ,t1.key
    ,t2a.value,IF(t2b.minid = t2a.id,1,0) is_first_entry
FROM
`TABLE-TWO` t2a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) minid,fk_id FROM `TABLE-TWO` GROUP BY fk_id) t2b ON t2a.fk_id = t2b. fk_id 
INNER JOIN `TABLE-ONE` t1 ON t1.id = t2a.fk_id
ORDER By id
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `TABLE-TWO`   (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `fk_id` INTEGER,
>   `value` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `TABLE-TWO`  
>   (`id`, `fk_id`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'v1'),
>   ('2', '1', 'v2'),
>   ('3', '1', 'v3'),
>   ('4', '2', 'v1'),
>   ('5', '2', 'v2'),
>   ('6', '3', 'v1'),
>   ('7', '3', 'v2'),
>   ('8', '3', 'v3'),
>   ('9', '3', 'v4'),
>   ('10', '3', 'v5');
>
> CREATE TABLE `TABLE-ONE` (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `key` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `TABLE-ONE`
>   (`id`, `key`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'k1'),
>   ('2', 'k2'),
>   ('3', 'k3');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   t2a.id
>   ,t1.key
>   ,t2a.value,IF(t2b.minid = t2a.id,1,0) is_first_entry
> FROM
> `TABLE-TWO` t2a 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) minid,fk_id FROM `TABLE-TWO` GROUP BY fk_id) t2b ON t2a.fk_id = t2b. fk_id 
> INNER JOIN `TABLE-ONE` t1 ON t1.id = t2a.fk_id
> ORDER By id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | key | value | is_first_entry
> -: | :-- | :---- | -------------:
>  1 | k1  | v1    |              1
>  2 | k1  | v2    |              0
>  3 | k1  | v3    |              0
>  4 | k2  | v1    |              1
>  5 | k2  | v2    |              0
>  6 | k3  | v1    |              1
>  7 | k3  | v2    |              0
>  8 | k3  | v3    |              0
>  9 | k3  | v4    |              0
> 10 | k3  | v5    |              0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c851ec562b613af682a15dd1572ca8d7)*

Comment: "Your list is unsorted and therefore gives a false result" -- Won't proper indexing solve this issue ?

Comment: no, a index won't solve it, you algorithm is based on the principle that the next entry is a new entry for a key or a new key, so it is not universal functioning. as shown in the firstg example 2 | k2  | v3   in not the first element , sp i think that is what you wanted to know

Comment: Don't think so. I have added the ORDER BY clause exactly for that reason.

Comment: As you can see in the example it doesn't work at all see bottom https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c851ec562b613af682a15dd1572ca8d7

Comment: I have updated the db-fiddle. Added primary keys and foreign keys. It seems to work fine. The effectiveness of the function depends on the order of rows that are being processed which makes indexing very important.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9f29412e9f59d0ec2e332b0c17cc97e6

Comment: You changed your query. Mine is simpler, has no need for a function, and is quicker. My answer is complete and correct.